# Union sentence gives error only referencing one column

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm using a table called Task and a sql union query for retrieving some tasks. All the info can be found here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/786e1/2

My problem is this:

When I use any column in the order by clause, (priority, start_date, completion_date...) it works perfectly, but whenever I put created_on it gives me the following error:

```
Unknown column 'created_on' in 'order clause'
```

Also, when trying `t`.`created_on` I keep having the same error:

```
Unknown column 't.created_on' in 'order clause'
```

In the fiddle I provided you can see the structure for Task table and the query I'm trying to run. I'd like to know why the union is not working with created_on column and how to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your sql fiddle is is missing few tables definition, could please correct your sql fiddle.

Comment: works just fine if i remove all the clutter in your SQL that was not defined in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but changing the sentence from columns to t.* made it work.

Thanks to everyone who helped me, Ill consider the responses if I ever encounter the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your SELECT statment in a subquery.
You must try something like this, 
In sqlfiddle there is no users table, so I changed your original query.
See the sample below, an try  the same aproach with your original query.
Sorry I don't speak english, Hope I helped you

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT t.id, 
       t.title, 
       t.owner, 
       t.created_on, 
       t.due_date, 
       t.completion_date, 
       t.start_date, 
       t.predecessor_id, 
       t.priority, 
       t.status, 
       t.performer_id, 
       t.delegate_id, 
       t.performer_type, 
       t.is_assigned, 
       t.review_required, 
       t.attachments
FROM   task t 
WHERE  t.performer_id IS NULL 
       AND t.is_returned = 0 
       AND t.status = 'active' 

union ALL

SELECT t.id, 
       t.title, 
       t.owner, 
       t.created_on, 
       t.due_date, 
       t.completion_date, 
       t.start_date, 
       t.predecessor_id, 
       t.priority, 
       t.status, 
       t.performer_id, 
       t.delegate_id, 
       t.performer_type, 
       t.is_assigned, 
       t.review_required, 
       t.attachments
FROM   task t 
WHERE  t.performer_id IS NULL 
       AND t.is_returned = 0 
       AND t.status = 'active' 

) as x
order by title
```